# Polymorphic relationship in doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to achieve the polymorphic relationship that Laravel have on doctrine?

Here is an example:

```
class Address
{
    protected $street;
    ...

    public function setStreet()
    {

    }

    public function getStreet()
    {

    }
}

class Event
{
    /*one to many*/
    protected $addresses;
    ...
}

class Museum
{
    /*one to many*/
    protected $addresses;
    ...
}
```

And on the database it would be something like this:

```
Address:
    id | type (event or museum) | type_id | street ...

Event:
    id | name ...

Museum:
    id | name ...
```

I looked at single table inheritance and it seems to solve my problem, but I did not understood how to associate the event or museum to the address. If someone could ELI5 I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does look like a use case for inheritance mapping, unless you have a ton of different entities you want to store addresses for. Using your example in Doctrine, you'd create two classes for each of your addresses.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"event" = "EventAddress", "museum" = "MuseumAddress"})
 */
class Address {
    protected $street;
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class EventAddress extends Address {
    protected $event;
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class MuseumAddress extends Address {
    protected $museum;
    // ...
}
```

Read more about [inheritance mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Comment: The $event and $museum would be the association? Like: 
   `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="addresses")protected $event;`
?

Comment: Yep, exactly. In the database an EventAddress will have an empty `museum_id` field and a MuseumAddress will have an empty `event_id` field.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a hard time trying to figure inheritance mapping, but now I think I have a clear picture of how it works.

Comment: If I could get a bit more clarification, on the one-to-many side of this (the event or museum entities), would the association reference the address entity or the sub-entity? Would it need to specify something like the type when mapping the association?

Comment: EventAddress and MuseumAddress are separate entities from the ORM's perspective, so you would want to reference them directly in your relationship. For example, for the `address` property on our `Museum` class we'd use this annotation: `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MuseumAddress", inversedBy="museum")`

Comment: what about when it is a many-to-many polymorphic relationship

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote any PHP, but in general this solution seems like the wrong approach to me now, especially in a case as complex as many to many polymorphic inheritance. Inheritance mapping smells of hard coupling your database schema to your object graph, which is an abuse of the RDBMS. [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/349677) explains the problem much better than I can, this many years removed from using an ORM like Doctrine. [This blog post](https://romaricdrigon.github.io/2019/06/11/doctrine-inheritance) also has some useful ideas.