# Building OneToMany and ManyToOne associations beetwen more than three tables via additional table Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Building associations beetwen more than three tables 
via additional [EntityTypes] table Doctrine2

I have next schema of database:

```
//==== some Tables ====

articles (
    id
    entity_type_id
)

posts (
    id
    entity_type_id
)

other... (
    id
    entity_type_id
)

//==== additional table of Types ====

entity_types (
    id
)

//==== Comments ====

comments (
    id
    entity_type_id
    entity_id
)
```

I use Symfony2 with Doctrine2 thereby I've been written next assotiations:

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityType", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
     */
    protected $comments;
}

class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityType", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post")
     */
    protected $comments;
}
...

class EntityType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="entityType")
     */
    protected $articles;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="entityType")
     */
    protected $posts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="entityType")
     */
    protected $comments;
}

class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityType", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $article;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $post;
}
```

There are no any mistakes in mapping and all operations are available 
including commenting articles
but an exception appeared when I'm trying to comment post

need someone to help...

Comment: Can you share with us the exception you are getting?

Comment: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO comments ( entity_type_id, entity_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null. 


I think that 'entity_type_id' cannot be null too

Comment: The Comment entity definition looks to be the cause: you have two relationships defined for the same join column (entity_id). You should probably use single table inheritance (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) to define separate entities for ArticleComment and PostComment (and any additional comment type you might have) using just the comment database table...

Comment: nice variant, but i would try to use polymorphic relations as in ruby on rails, is it possible by this way? (or expediently?)

Comment: if i thougt right i have to increase the amount of entitiesComments whithout increasing number of thats tables in db?

Comment: yeah, if you use the single table inheritance you just increase the number of entities. There are some other so questions about polymorphic relations in symfony (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488990/polymorphic-relationship-in-doctrine-2 for example) and the answer seems to be to use (single) table inheritance

Comment: so, as far as i understood i will have only Entity-tables without table of types, right?

Comment: is the following correct?

    //==== some Tables ====
    
    articles (
        id
    )
    
    posts (
        id
    )
    
    other... (
        id
    )
    
    
    //==== Comments ====
    
    comments (
        id
        article_type_for_comment
        post_type_for_comment
        other_type_for_comment
    )

or plan B

    //==== Comments ====
    
    comments (
        id
        type_for_comment
    )

Comment: Plan B is the way to go: additionally you still need the entity_id value in the comments table