# Inheritance relationship with interfaces in symfony/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have entities like this :

Request.php (parent)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RequestRepository::class)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "requestA" = "RequestA",
 *      "requestB" = "RequestB"
 * })
 */
abstract class Request
{
    /*...*/
}
```

RequestA.php (child A)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DemenagementRepository::class)
 */
class RequestA extends Request implements AddressEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Address::class, inversedBy="request")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    // +others...
}
```

RequestB.php (child B)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DemenagementRepository::class)
 */
class RequestB extends Request implements AddressEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Address::class, inversedBy="request")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    // +others...
}
```

AddressEntityInterface.php

```php
interface AddressEntityInterface
{
    public function getAddress(): ?Address;
    public function setAddress(Address $address): self;
}
```

Address.php

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AddressRepository::class)
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=??????, mappedBy="address")
     */
    private $request;

    public function getRequest() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I want to use getRequest() revert relationship how can i do for make targetEntity dynamically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need **polymorphic relationships** or as they like to call them from docrine '**Inheritance Mapping**'

I leave you some sites to view on which you can find everything you need

[Official Documentation (Doctrine)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

[Stackoverflow Practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488990/polymorphic-relationship-in-doctrine-2)

[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNAMEWYCkAM)

[Stackoverflow, discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027651/creating-a-one-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-with-doctrine) <-
personally I advise you to **read all** this so you get a concrete idea of ​​what you need

I hope my little routing will help you.

Comment: It would be better to give a more concrete example with the classes given by the question. It would be quite a pain if every SO answers were just link to the documentation.

Comment: Request is already a polymorphic class (i have updated the topic with this class)